# Is "a lot" a kind of pleonasm with "has been raining"?

Tags: word-choice

> It has been raining a **lot** since you have been here.

Is it OK to add **a lot** to this sentence because been raining almost constantly? Is it not a [pleonasm](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pleonasm):  the use of more words than are necessary to explain the concept.

Comment: The language is chock full of idiomatic pleonasms, from *free gift* to *join together*; there is no real need to avoid them. .

Answer (score 3):

Raining a lot is a perfectly acceptable phrase in English.

It is *not a pleonasm* because it is being used to describe how much it has been raining since the person left.

> It has been raining since you left.

This means it hasn't stopped raining since you left.

> It has been raining a lot since you left.

It has rained quite often (but not necessarily continuously) since you left.

---

Side note. I had to look up the word *pleonasm* to answer you.  Your usage of it is perfectly correct, but it is very obscure to most native speakers.  Most English speakers would say *redundant* or *extraneous*.